# Running Scala Script in sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt

How can i run a scala script inside a sbt project which can access all classes of the sbt project and typesafe config as well? Basically I want the script to run in a similar way as the sbt console.

Comment: i was just directly writing a .scala file in project and running it with scalac but that obvs fails

Comment: You should have a look at the SBT quickstart doc

Answer (score 0):

one option is to assemble a jar using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

you would need to add the following to a .sbt file to your project directory

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

and add a minimum of two lines to your build file.

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := "something.jar"

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.Main")
```

then you can run the 'assembly' task from sbt, this will build and executable "fat" jar with all your dependencies and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the launcher and the command system to implement an interactive appliation with autocomplete etc.

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Applications.html

You have to invoke the application separately, though; I don't think it is possible to run it directly from the `sbt` prompt within the application directory.